# How can you send an SMS message using pure HTTP post with no other libraries

Tags: twilio

I know you can use HTTP POST passing in 'from', 'to' and 'body' as http parameters. But how can you send 'account sid' and 'auth token'? Can you use a request header or something? I would like to post without using PHP or Curl or any other libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

As you mention to make a raw request to the Twilio REST API without a helper library you need to craft your own HTTP request.  The specific [HTTP Method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) you use for the request (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) depends on what you want the API to do.

Twilio uses simple [Basic authorization](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) to authorize users of the API.  To use Basic Authentication with HTTP you need to include in your HTTP request the [`Authorization`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header and pass as its value the authorization scheme (in Twilio case this is "Basic") and a Base64 encoded string containing your accountsid and authtoken seperated by a semi-colon:

```
[AccountSid]:[AuthToken]
```

The HTTP header would end up looking something like this:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

For example of you wanted to have Twilio send a text message you would craft an HTTP request using the POST method that looks like this:

```
POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]/Messages HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
Host: api.twilio.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 50

To=+15555555555&From=+16666666666&Body=Hello World
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!! I changed the URI slightly https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID]/Messages

Comment: Is it possible to use this method with an Alpha Sender ID? I've tried the simple "replace From with a name" and now i'm trying to use the messaging_service_id method but it always insists on a "From" number.